# not getting checkbox true and false values for multiple checkboxes, angular

Tags: angular

this is my checkbox in the template

```
 <label class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let option of options">
                    <input
                      type="checkbox"
                      name="{{ option.name }}"
                      (change)="onChangeOptions($event)"
                    />{{ option.value }}
                  </label>
```

In TS file

```
 days: any = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "repeat_1",
      isActive: true,
      value: "1"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "repeat_2",
      isActive: false,
      value: "2"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "repeat_3",
      isActive: false,
      value: "3"
    }
  ];

      public onChangeOptions(event): void {
        const a = event.target.checked;
        console.log("display val",a);
      }
```

i am just getting false or true value which changes with every checkbox, it acts as common checkbox, 
i want true false vals in an array, so that i can assign them to my global variables repeat_1, repeat_2 repeat_3 accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The checkbox will only ever return true/false. You need pass the option to your onChangeOptions() function, and if the checkbox is true, utilise the value from the option:

```
<label class="checkbox-inline" *ngFor="let option of options">
  <input
   type="checkbox"
   name="{{ option.name }}"
   (change)="onChangeOptions($event, option)"
  />{{ option.value }}
</label>
```

```
public onChangeOptions(event, option): void {
   const a = event.target.checked;

   if (a === true) {
     console.log("display val", option.value);
   }
}
```

Comment: what will these vals be stored in...i need to put them in repeat_option1, repeat_option2 global variables

Comment: you could do something like window['repeat_option_' + option.id'] = option.value